# AppCode and Mercurial integration issue

Tags: version-control, mercurial, ide, appcode

When trying to access Mercurial commands in [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/), I get the following error message:

> abort: repository /src/project/subfolder1 not found!

This is indeed correct, the repository is /src/project, not /src/project/subfolder1.

However, the project file resides in /src/project/subfolder1/.
I have tried with "`Run hg as bash -c`" and without in AppCode, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

in my system this is `/usr/local/bin/hg`